# Rails STI: transfer records from one model to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I have a model called `Coupons`
Then I have two child models `CouponApplications`and `ApprovedCoupons`.
The last two inherit from `Coupons`via an STI architecture.

Now I want to realise the following:

1. A user sees CouponApplications
2. He clicks on an Approve button which makes the `CouponApplications` `ApprovedCoupons`

I realise that I could simply update the `type`column of the `Coupons`record to change types. However, there are several Concerns, hooks etc in the `ApprovedCoupons` model which are happening after creation so this is not so easy. In fact, I want to create a complete new record to trigger those Concerns, hooks etc.

So I wrote this which I consider really bad:

```
@coupon_application = CouponApplication.find(params[:id])
@approved_coupon = ApprovedCoupon.new

# copy/paste attributes except the ID as this would be considered a duplication
@approved_coupon.attributes = @coupon_application.attributes.except("id")

# set the new type
@approved_coupon.update_attributes(type: "Advertisement")

@approved_coupon.save
```

I hope you understand what I want to achieve. It works this way but I doubt this is clean code.

To summarize:

- I want to change the `Coupon`type from `CouponApplication` to
  `ApprovedCoupon`
- I still want to trigger the Concerns, hooks etc. in my `ApprovedCoupon` model so I decided to create a new `ApprovedCoupon`
  record instead of just changing the type.

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `approve` method to your `CouponApplication` model like this:

```
class CouponApplication < Coupon
  ...

  def approve
    data = attributes.except('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
    ApprovedCoupon.create(data.merge(type: 'Advertisement'))
  end
end
```

Now your code can be simplified to this:

```
@coupon_application = CouponApplication.find(params[:id])
@approved_coupon = @coupon_application.approve
```